# Android Studio's windows flickering on OSX VM

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, osx-elcapitan, vmware-workstation

I installed OSX EL Capitan on VM, and the base OS is Windows 8.
I 'm using Android Studio in VM, and when I type or click in the window, the screen flickers.
But when I stop typing or clicking, or switch to other windows, it does not happen.
Is this kind of a performance issue? Did you face this issue before?

Android Studio version : 2.2.3

OSX version : 10.11

VMWare Workstation version : 11.1.0

Comment: I am also facing this issue. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue also.

I resolved it by updating OSX to the latest version, and the flicking was gone.

Please give it a try.
Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, I will try and let you know.

Comment: Which version worked for you? I am using OSX 10.12.6 and the screen flickers.